# Necesito una la siguiente dll, Infragistics2.Win.v6.1.Design

Tags: c#

tengo una aplicacion realizada en c# y cuando la quiero compilar me da errores.

Estoy detectando que me esta faltando al siguiente DLL: **Infragistics2.Win.v6.1.Design**. ¿Alguien me podrá decir desde donde la puedo descargar?

También he intentado descaragar la version 2006 de NET Advabtage version 3 CLR2.0, pero no la puedo encontrar, si no me equivoco debería estar allí adentro.

Desde ya muchas gracias si me pueden ayudar.
Saludos cordiales, Leonardo .

Comment: Infragistics es una libreria que forma parte de un producto comercial, pasarte la dll implica una infraccion de licencias. Deberias consultar quien agrego la referencia a la libreria y pedirle como registrarla o como instalar la suit del producto

Comment: Gracias por lo menos me sacas de la duda, muy amable.!!!